# Python multiprocessing - access running process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a process running with `Process(...).start()`
What's the preferred way of controlling the process?
Currently I have a WebSocket listener, that takes JSON data and then controls the methods.

So for the sake of an example, say we have

```
def run_this():
    while True:
       print('.')

def foo():
    print('Foo')

Process(name='bar', target=run_this).start()
```

run_this() is run as a process, and I want to be able to call foo() from another module.

Comment: I've used `multiprocessing.queue` to great effect for several projects as a pipe for passing commands and returning data from worker processes.

Comment: Add `import another_module` at the top; call `another_module.foo()` in `run_this()`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Imagine opening a console, running this file, so that a bunch of dots are printed. Then I open another console, where I 'call' the method foo, and in the first console 'Foo' appears in between dots. I probably will end up implementing a queue, but I still don't like it a lot

Comment: @Aaron What would be my reasoning to not keep using a WebSocket in this scenario and implement it with a queue?

Comment: @akalikin: it is how linux was born ([search for word `terminal`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awb/linux.history.html)). Are you writing a new OS? The question is too broad: to accept user input while doing some other task, you could use any concurrency pattern: threads/processes, nonblocking/async. io (event loop). I don't see any connection between websocket and multiprocessing module. Could you describe the context?